# When deploying shinyapp to shinyapps.io german characters are not shown correctly

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app which works fine locally on my Windows10, but when deployed to shinyapps.io German characters like Ä, ü in the data are not shown correctly.

The data is saved as a csv from within R:

```
test <- data.frame(a = "Für", b = 1)
write.csv2(test, file = "data.csv", row.names = FALSE)
```

This is a simple example app:

global.R

```
library(shiny)
data <- read.csv2("data.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

ui.R

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  textOutput("text")
)
```

server.R

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$text <- renderText(data$a)
}
```

I have also tried `read.csv2(..., encoding = "utf8")`, which does not change anything. ui.R, server.R and global.R are all saved as utf8.

Does someone know a solution for this?

Thanks.

Comment: What about the original file, can you prove it's UTF-8? Have you tried `UTF-8` (notice the case)?

Comment: No. Where can I look up the encoding of the csv file? UTF-8 does not work

Comment: I tried `encoding = "latin1"`, then Ä is shown as Ã¼

Comment: I usually use Notepad++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, which works for me :)

Encode the csv file as `"UTF-8"` by using `file`:

```
test <- data.frame(a = "Für", b = 1)
f <- file('data.csv', encoding = "UTF-8")
write.csv(test, file = f, row.names = FALSE)
```

Use `read.csv` instead of `read.csv2` in global.R with specified encoding `"UTF-8"`:

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", encoding = "UTF-8", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```